# Laravel Eloquent : Record of Records for model instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1, query-builder

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way of getting the index of the given Model in the Collection.

Scenario : list of videos, which belong to a specific title. Title can have one or more videos. When on the given video page with the `Video` model at hand, I would like to display something along the lines `Video ? of ?`.

Basically what I need to achieve is something that would reflect the following, raw sql statement:

```
SELECT `v`.*
(
    SELECT COUNT(`id`)
    FROM `videos`
    WHERE `title_id` = ?
    AND `identity` <= `v`.`identity`
) AS `collection_index`
FROM `videos` `v`
WHERE `v`.`id` = ?
```

Where `identity` is simply some field that is used to sort videos - might be numerical but also string in the format `01-03` etc. In the above `collection_index` would store the index (or rather sequential position) of the given record in the collection.

Is it possible with a single statement on the Eloquent model - anyone came across a similar problem?

**UPDATE / SOLUTION**

After some digging and help from @JarekTkaczyk, I've managed to come up with a solution - for those who also might face the same problem.
Here's my model using sub-query to achieve the above.

```
return Video::select('videos.*')
    ->selectSub("
        SELECT COUNT(v.id)
        FROM videos as v
        WHERE v.title_id = videos.title_id
        AND v.identity <= videos.identity
        ",
        'collection_index'
    )
    ->selectSub("
        SELECT COUNT(v.id)
        FROM videos as v
        WHERE v.title_id = videos.title_id
        ",
        'collection_count'
    )
    ->find(id);
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is a Laravel specific question. You have a result set, ordering of which is defined by your specific conditions. When you are on the detail page, your result set is lost. You have only detailed record.

So, you might want to cache position of each video in the list, for example.